# Changing Namespace in a safe manner

Tags: wpf, xaml

This might be a very newbie question (coming from a newbie) but I had some problems regarding the namespace. I've created a User Interface in Visual Studio and gave it a test name to start off and learn how to use the program and the programming language. I kept building and building my UI and now I'm at the point that I'm actually pretty satisfied with my work (and this community's help!). So I decided to change the name of the file from "Test" to something more relevant for my work.

Yet, unfortunately, I ran into some problems regarding the change of the Namespace. I know there are a lot of tabs where it needs to be changed, but I was wondering if there is an easy way to change the file name/namespace of the UI?

Thank you in andvance for replying and taking the time to explain this newbie what to do without breaking his UI ;)

Comment: I don't understand the donwvote, it's a legit question about programming tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tool like [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it will do it for you automatically and safely.

**With Keyboard shortcut:**
Put the keyboard cursor to the namespace, press Ctrl + R + R and set the new name. It will change the namespace inside XAML as well.

**With Mouse:**
Right mouse click on the name space, click Refactor > Rename.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it!

Comment: Resharper can be said, must have for C# developers.

Answer (score 1):

When renaming classes and variables there is the lightbulb-menu (*Ctrl + .*) in witch you can give Visual Studio the instruction to Change it for you. But this will not work with Xaml.

Visual Studio will not change Namespaces as far as I'm concerned. But you can still compile and look at the "Namespace not found"-Errors to change them manually.

As [Yohanes Nurcahyo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45230966/8257769) said there is ReSharper but only has a free Trial of 30 days.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes,I was familiar with the light-bulb menu and I did notice the problem with in Xaml. I will take a look at the free trial as suggested by Yohanes Nurcayho.